# How to make transparent Activity with 50% transparency

Tags: android

I have a transparent theme Activity but this theme will make the Activity 100% transparent.
I need a code such that the Activity will be 50% Transparent. This is my code:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set background to @color/#50000000, 50 is the alpha channel of the color

Comment: where can I set this color??
You mean in the theme ?

Comment: yeah,don't now if it works, but you could try: <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/#50000000</item>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could apply a transparent theme to the required activity. Create a new style in `/res/values/style.xml`

```
<resources>
<style name="Transparent">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
<item name ="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

The value of transparent is

```
<color name="transparent">#80000000</color>
```

Now in AndroidManifest.xml declare the theme of the activity to the one you just created.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:theme="@style/Transparent"></activity>
```